# Why does the progress callback receive the same value every time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm playing around with promises and jQuery and I came up with the code below:

```
var timeoutAsync = function(millis) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function () { deferred.notify(millis); deferred.resolve(); }, millis);
    return deferred.promise();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var firstPromise = timeoutAsync(1000);
    var secondPromise = timeoutAsync(2000);
    var thirdPromise = timeoutAsync(3000);
    var fourthPromise = timeoutAsync(1234);
    $.when(firstPromise, secondPromise, thirdPromise, fourthPromise)
        .done(function() { alert("LOL"); })
        .fail(function() { alert("FAIL"); })
        .progress(function(msg) { console.log(msg); });
});
```

I'd expect my console to show me four values, namely: `1000`, `1234`, `2000` and `3000`.
And it did when I put a console.log statement in the setTimeout callback. But with the code above I get `1000` four times.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something here but I can't seem to find a hint in the docs as to why this would happen. So why does this happen?

I'm using jQuery 2.1.1 and I'm testing on firefox but it also happens in IE.

Comment: This *might* be of help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537939/using-jquerys-deferred-with-settimeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're creating four different deferreds, and passing them all to `$.when`.
This creates a set of arguments for the progress handler

If you do it like this

```
.progress(function(msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4) { 
     console.log(msg1, msg2, msg3, msg4); 
});
```

You'll see the arguments as the deferreds are resolved

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkepqk5v/)

In other words, you're logging only the first argument, which is the value passed to the first deferred, every time.

When checking progress you have to use **one** deferred object, and then use the notify and progress methods on that deferred, you shouldn't create four different deferreds.

Something like

```
var timeoutAsync = function(deferred, millis) {
    setTimeout(function () { 
        deferred.notify(millis); 
    }, millis);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    var firstPromise = timeoutAsync(deferred, 1000);
    var secondPromise = timeoutAsync(deferred, 2000);
    var thirdPromise = timeoutAsync(deferred, 3000);
    var fourthPromise = timeoutAsync(deferred, 1234);

    deferred.done(function() { alert("LOL"); })
            .fail(function() { alert("FAIL"); })
            .progress(function(msg) { 
                console.log(msg); 
            });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nkepqk5v/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. After reading your answer I read up on the docs for progress() and it does (in a way ..) say what you're saying. But definitly not as clear as you've explained it.